# Spring-Kafka Batch Not Updating Offsets with Larger Batches

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've set up a Kafka Consumer in a Spring Boot App using the batch patterns from the Spring Kafka docs. It appeared to be working until we put load on the topics. Then the offsets didn't update and it would process the same batch of consumer messages over and over again.

By default the batch sizes appear to be dynamic based on some algorithm in the framework. So as the topics got more and more behind it went from batching of hundreds of messages to thousands. I was able to work around the issue by setting the batch size (max.poll.records) to 25, but I'm not really trusting Kafka/Spring-Kafka until I understand root cause.

Batches take between 3000ms and 15000ms to complete.

Properties for the factory:

```
    public Map<String, Object> getKafkaConfigurationProperties() {
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> builderMap = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
            .put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Joiner.on(',').join(getBootstrapServers()))
            .put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, getKeyDeserializer())
            .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100)
            .put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false)
            .put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000)
            .put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, getValueDeserializer())
            .put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 25);

    String groupId = getConsumerGroup();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(groupId)) {
        builderMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    }

    return builderMap.build();

}
```

Factory Build:

```
private KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> makeKafkaListener(
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory, KafkaConsumerConfiguration configuration) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency(6);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
}
```

The listener service uses the annotions:

```
@KafkaListener(
        containerFactory = "serviceListenerContainerFactory",
        group = "kafkaListenerContainers",
        id = "widgetListener",
        topics = "widget.topic.prod")
public void listenProduct(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecordList) { ... stuff ... }
```

Comment: Take a look here, please: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/199. Seems for me you have the same rebalance and lost commits issue. Consider to use `MANUAL` ack mode. And share, please, some DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework.kafka` category

Comment: I was running all the way to trace the other day and nothing really stood out.   

`DEBUG o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records`
`DEBUG o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}`
`DEBUG o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 50 records`
`DEBUG o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}`